#  *** Exception: Prelude.read: no parse in Haskell - Parsing, Expressions and Recursion

Tags: parsing, haskell, expression

This portion of code should read in two or more numbers (main io function omitted), then a "+" to give the sum. Rationals are used because later i will do multiplications and such other operations.

```
data Expression =  Number Rational
               | Add (Expression)(Expression)
               deriving(Show,Eq)

solve :: Expression -> Expression
solve (Add (Number x) (Number y)) = Number (x + y)

parse :: [String] -> [Expression] -> Double
parse ("+":s)(a:b:xs) = parse s (solve (Add a b):xs)
parse [] (answer:xs) = fromRational (toRational (read (show answer)::Float))
parse (x:xs) (y) = parse (xs) ((Number (toRational (read x::Float))):y)
```

The (second) error is with the parse function unable to handle

```
*Main> parse ["1","2","+"] [Number 3]

*** Exception: Prelude.read: no parse
```

I have looked on the Data.Ratio page and on the web for this solution but haven't found it and would appreciate some help. Thanks,

CSJC

Comment: Your second error is already treated in my answer :)

Comment: Yes, it seems you had already preempted such a thing as i was typing it out!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first equation,

```
parse ("+":s)(a:b:xs) = parse (s)((solve (Add (Number a) (Number b))):xs)
```

should be

```
parse ("+":s)(a:b:xs) = parse (s)((solve (Add a b)):xs)
```

since per the type signature, `a` and `b` already are `Expression`s.

**Or**, in line with the second and third equations, change the type to

```
parse :: [String] -> [Rational] -> Double
```

and change the first equation to

```
parse ("+":s)(a:b:xs) = parse s ((a + b):xs)
```

Two possible ways of fixing the code (there were more problematic parts):

```
-- Complete solve to handle all cases
solve :: Expression -> Expression
solve expr@(Number _) = expr
solve (Add (Number x) (Number y)) = Number (x + y)
solve (Add x y) = solve (Add (solve x) (solve y))

-- Convert an Expression to Double
toDouble :: Expression -> Double
toDouble (Number x) = fromRational x
toDouble e = toDouble (solve e)

-- parse using a stack of `Expression`s
parse :: [String] -> [Expression] -> Double
parse ("+":s) (a:b:xs) = parse s ((solve (Add a b)):xs)
parse [] (answer:_) = toDouble answer
parse (x:xs) ys = parse xs (Number (toRational (read x :: Double)) : ys)
parse _ _ = 0

-- parse using a stack of `Rational`s
parseR :: [String] -> [Rational] -> Double
parseR ("+":s) (a:b:xs) = parseR s (a+b : xs)
parseR [] (answer:xs) = fromRational answer
parseR (x:xs) y = parseR xs ((toRational (read x::Double)):y)
parseR _ _ = 0
```

The latter is rather circumspect, since in the end a `Double` is produced, there's no real point using `Rational`s for the stack.

In your code for `parse`, the third equation leaves out the conversion of a `Rational` to an `Expression` via the `Number` constructor, but is otherwise fine. The second equation, however, contains a different type of problem:

```
parse [] (answer:xs) = fromRational (toRational (read (show answer)::Float))
```

If `answer` is either an `Expression` or a `Rational`, `show answer` cannot be parsed as a `Float`, so that will lead to a runtime error, as exemplified by your edit:

> The (second) error is with the parse function unable to handle

```
*Main> parse ["1","2","+"] [Number 3]
*** Exception: Prelude.read: no parse
```

At the point where the second equation is used, the first element (`answer`) on the stack is `Number (3 % 1)`, and `show (Number (3 % 1))` is `"Number (3 % 1)"`, which is not a `String` that `read` can parse as a `Float`.

Comment: Does this also hold for 'solve (Add (Number x) (Number y)) = Number (x + y)' can be 'solve (Add x y) = Number (x + y)'?

Comment: No. In `Add x y`, `x` and `y` are `Expression`s, but `Number` takes a `Rational` argument, and `(+)` isn't defined for `Expression`s. `solve` is correct as far as it's implemented (it's incomplete, of course).

Comment: This is very useful, especially your explanation of the second equation of the parse function; something i overlooked. It now works for all Rationals under addition.